# Reinstalling windows from repair disk using 64 instead of 32

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, windows-installation, product-key

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W510 running Windows 7 Ultimate.  Before my warranty ran out, I sent it in to have some repairs done which included replacing my hard drive and reinstalling Windows.
I had been running 64 bits, but they mistakenly installed 32 bits.  At the time, I needed my pc, and didn't need the extra processing power, so I didn't bother with it.
Now I am about to reinstall Windows because it's full of junk, and I want a clean slate.
I have several possible routes:
1.  Can I reinstall Windows 7 using the repair disk, but opt for a 64 bit os at install time?
2.  I have another install disk for Windows 7 Pro.  Can I install this and use the product key for ultimate that is on the bottom of my pc?
3.  Should I just install Linux and say  'F it!' to all the complexity involved in Operating System monopolization and deliberate consumer confusion? (This is tongue and cheek.  I know that the myth of the Microsoft boogie-men was written by grumpy children - I just feel like a grumpy child about this right now).

Comment: What's that actual problem here?  What happens when you put the disk in and run the installer? Make a backup and go for it. PS: you can call Microsoft, support calls regarding keys and activation are free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register Windows 7 Pro with the key for your other Windows, Windows 7 Ultimate. If you have 32bit Windows installed, you can not change it to 64bits with just repairing. So, you need a fresh install of your Windows and during install choose 64bits version. And, of course you can install Linux as a second OS.

Comment: But using the repair disk with Windows 7, can I choose to do a fresh install, and then choose 64 bits at that time?

Comment: @user1167442 - You can do anything you want if you choose to install a fresh installation of Windows.  The installation you replace will be gone though.

Comment: That's fine.  I guess what I'm asking is:  can I use a repair disk I make with Lenovo tools to do a fresh install?

Comment: @user1167442 Exactly, if you do clean install your previous Windows installation will be removed, meaning, during installation you need to choose that option. I do clean Windows installation on my PC from time to time. So, during that process I usually first format partition with Windows I want to remove, and then I install my fresh Windows copy.

Comment: Thanks!  I even found an old repair disk from when it was 64 bits.  So that may or may not make it smoother, but it'll for it!